# Firestore streamSnapshot if statement error in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm inquiring about an error in the process of developing the flutter and firestore.

First, I imported a snapshot of the FirebaseFirestore collection to StreamBuilder and listed it as a card using ListView.builder.
So far, it has gone well without any problems.

But If the value of ["0_competing_where"]' is not 0, it shows the card, and if it is 0, I want to put together a code that doesn't show the card, so I tied the return GestureDetector to if (WhereOrNot! = 0).

Here, if you change the value of the second and third collections to 0, that card disappears, but if you change the value of the first collection to 0, all cards disappear.

Is this a bug?
Or did I make the wrong code?

```
Expanded(
    child: StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('championship').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
        if(streamSnapshot.hasData){
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index];
              ///Send Competition_main_page(onTap)
              void sendCompetition_main_page(){
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => competition_main_page(documentSnapshot:documentSnapshot),
                  ),
                );
              }

              final WhetherOrNot = documentSnapshot['0_competition_Whether'];
              

              if(WhetherOrNot != 0){
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: sendCompetition_main_page,
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 0,
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 3),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 100,
                            height: 100,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                const Text('competition', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19),),
                                Text(whetherornotValue, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: 1.4,
                            height: 100,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                width: 1,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 15,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(documentSnapshot['1_main_competition'],
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 17,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.black87,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                Text(documentSnapshot['2_place'],
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
          );
        } else {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
    },
  ),
)
```

"documentSnapshot['0_complement_where']"

I changed the value to text because I thought it was a number, but I failed.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it.

The solution is as follows.

If the field value of the database is zero, setting the invisible can be solved without errors by changing the stream without using the If statement.

Delete the if statement.

And change it to the code below.

```
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('championship').where("0_competition_Whether", isNotEqualTo: 0).snapshots(),
```